# Como eu coloco um botão dentro de iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Tentei de várias formas e não consegui. Fiz assim:

```
<iframe id="ifrTeste" >
 <input type="button" /> ou <button...></button>
</iframe>
```

Não consegui fazer aparecer o botão dentro do iframe.

Comment: Isso não existe. o iFrame chama uma página pelo atributo `SRC`. E dentro da página você pode colocar o botão.

Comment: Então não tem como eu chamar um iframe so e dentro dele um botão. Isso não é possível, pelo que estou entendendo.

Comment: Mas qual é seu objetivo para querer fazer isso ? Existem outras maneiras de se fazer. Não tem como colocar elementos dentro de um iFrame.

Comment: Porque você está utilizando um iframe? Qual a finalidade do botão?

Comment: O iframe,não é uma tag que será aberta e fechada com elementos entre essa tag, ela é um objeto que renderiza um elemento externo através do **source** do arquivo **src="botao.html"**, para você colocar um botão dentro de um iframe, você deve construir duas páginas, uma para o botão e outra para inserir o iframe.

Comment: @IvanFerrer, valeu. O Diego Souza já havia me falado isso. Pessoal, nem sempre temos o controle da situação. O motivo agora é um teste que eu estou fazendo, para saber como se faz, pois será pedido algo semelhante e terei que saber, por isso a pergunta. Sei que olhando assim não tem objetivo nenhum, mas tem sim. Todo esse site que eu estou trabalhando é baseado em IFrame, todo ele e feito em ASP. Por ser um site extremamente gigante(trabalho em uma parte apenas), claro não há como refazê-lo com uma tecnologia mais nova.

Answer (score 4):

Amigo, fica mais facil se você deixar alguns pontos claros a respeito do iframe e o que você pretende fazer.

- **O domain do iframe é o mesmo da pagina na qual ele esta inserido ?**

  Você não tem permissão para alterar o conteudo de um iframe que pertence a um outro dominio, por exemplo, se a sua pagina esta rodando em http://localhost e o seu iframe tem o atributo src com o valor http://google.com, por exemplo, você não vai poder fazer nenhuma alteração no conteudo deste iframe.
- **Você deseja adicionar o botão dinamicamente utilizando Javascript** ?

  Caso você deseja apenas adicionar um botão e tem acesso ao arquivo que o iframe referencia é mais fácil alterar este arquivo diretamente, caso você precise fazer isto dinamicamente com Javascript você pode acessar o conteúdo do iframe com `window.frames[0].document`. Lembre-se, você so poderá alterar utilizando Javascript se o conteúdo do iframe estiver no mesmo dominio da sua pagina.

Neste link você pode aprender um pouco mais sobre o elemento iframe e como utiliza-lo https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Answer (score 3):

Utilize um DIV para este objetivo, um iFrame serve para carregar outro HTML, outro arquivo.

Comment: Isto não fornece uma resposta à pergunta. Para criticar ou solicitar esclarecimento de um autor, deixe um comentário abaixo da publicação dele - você sempre pode comentar em suas próprias publicações e quando tiver [pontos de reputação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficientes você poderá [comentar sobre qualquer publicação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: O projeto aqui é todo baseado em IFrame e eu estou fazendo um teste para uma alteração que será feita, razão pela qual deve ser feito co IFrame. Se fosse por mim, não seria nem feito em ASP, como é o caso aqui. Estou apenas seguindo o fluxo aqui. É um portal gigantesco que não vamos alterar, apenas fazer funcionar umas coisas que no momento estão dando erros.

Answer (score 0):

Assim como os demais colegas, não consigo ver utilidade nesta abordagem, mas uma possibilidade é criar um documento em memoria:

```js
var iFrames = document.querySelectorAll("[data-content]");
[].forEach.call(iFrames, function(frameElement, indice) {
  var frameContent = document.getElementById(frameElement.dataset.content);
  var blob = new Blob([frameContent.innerHTML], { type: "text/html" });
  frameElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  frameContent.parentNode.removeChild(frameContent);
});
```

```html
<iframe id="frame1" data-content="frameContent1"></iframe>
<iframe id="frame2" data-content="frameContent2"></iframe>

<script id="frameContent1" type="text/template">
    <input type="button" value="Enviar 01" />
</script>

<script id="frameContent2" type="text/template">
    <input type="button" value="Enviar 02" />
</script>
```

P.S: a técnica acima é bastante útil quando se deseja imprimir apenas um trecho da pagina e o uso de `@media print` não é o suficiente para se alcançar o resultado desejado.