# Criando Página Com Objetivo Similar Ao Site JSfiddle

Tags: javascript, iframe

De tanto ter que Abrir o editor de texto predileto para criar página HTML afim de efetuar testes de CSS e JScript, resolvi criar uma página pessoal baseada em alguns aspectos de sites terceiros do tipo "Jsfiddle", código bem simples, não, não me orgulho dele. Apenas fiz porque isso agiliza no meu desenvolvimento sem antes ter que criar o arquivo final(documento HTML).

## Código

```
<html>

<head>

<style>

#menu-vertical
{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999; 
    overflow: hidden;
    border-right: 1px dashed silver;
    padding: 5px;
    height:100%;
    float: left;
}

textarea
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    border: 3px solid silver;
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
    background-color: azure;
    background-position: bottom right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

input 
{ 
width: 90px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 5px; 
}

</style>

<script>
<!--

function pop()
{
var js = document.getElementById("JS").value;

var html = document.getElementById("HTML").value;

var css = document.getElementById("CSS").value;

var janela = window.open("", "janela","width=500px, height=500px, scrollbars=yes");

janela.document.write("<html>\n<head>\n");

janela.document.write("<style>\n"+css+"\n</style>\n");

janela.document.write("</head>\n<body>\n"+html+"\n");

janela.document.write("</body>\n<script>\n"+js+"\n");

janela.document.write("</script>\n</html>");
}

//-->
</script>

</head>

<body>

<!-- Editor Lang.: CSS - HTML - JS -->
<div id="menu-vertical">

<br><b>CSS:</b><br>

<textarea id="CSS" cols="39" rows="9" size="1"></textarea>

<br><b>HTML:</b><br>

<textarea id="HTML" cols="39" rows="9" size="1"></textarea>

<br><b>JScript:</b><br>

<textarea id="JS" cols="39" rows="9" size="1"></textarea>

<center>

<hr color="silver" width="100%" size="1"/>

<input type="button" value="Executar" onclick="pop()"/>

</div>
<!-- Fim -->

</center>

</body>

</html>
```

No demais perfeito, agora quero substituir a Janela Pop-up para `iframe` dinâmico, só não estou sabendo recriar as variáveis da função `pop()` para a função `pag()` do `iframe`.

```
var js = document.getElementById("JS").value;

var html = document.getElementById("HTML").value;

var css = document.getElementById("CSS").value;
```

## Iframe dinâmico

```
pag = function ()
{
var el = document.createElement('iframe');
el.setAttribute('id','exibir') ;
el.width ="100%";
el.height="100%";
document.body.appendChild(el);
}
```

Cito algo relacionado à esta pergunta ..

[Diddle](https://github.com/nwoike/Diddle) - *"É um clone simplificado do jsFiddle criado por nwoike"*

[image]

**Fonte:** [Como criar uma versão simplificada do jsFiddle](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/83652/como-criar-uma-vers%C3%A3o-simplificada-do-jsfiddle)

Comment: Comece com a idéia de criar um [iframe](https://ricardospinoza.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/exemplo-de-como-criar-iframe-via-javascript/) na página e não uma nova janela.

Comment: Diego só pra avisar tinha alguns erros no código da resposta, agora corrigi, espero que ajude.

Comment: Qual browser deseja rodar, nem tudo será possivel :/ ... vou tentar editar

Comment: @Guilherme Nascimento Sua resposta em si ja me agrada! Não será preciso modificá-la por conta disso. Mas sabendo de outra maneira de abranger navegadores modesto, bastaria somente adicionar outra lógica abaixo da primeira resposta, se souber, nada obrigatório Ok! Quanto ao Navegador utilizo uma certa  variedade familiares ao menos conhecidos é por isso que desejo ser portável Firefox2,3.. IEca rsrs Konqueror

Comment: Pronto diego, consegui testar no IE6, demais navegadores eu não sei qual será o efeito, mas acredito que funcione.

Comment: @Guilherme Nascimento Testado no: Konqueror Light, Flock 1.0, Flock 1.5,Firefox 1.0.4, Firefox 1.5.0.6, Firefox 2.0, Opera 8.01, Opera 8.01, Opera 8.25, Opera 8.50, Opera 8.52, Opera 9.10, Opera 9.25, .. enfim acho melhor recorrer alguns plugins para este caso em específico, usar os recursos das versões novas e prover [shims](https://github.com/termi/ES5-DOM-SHIM) ou [polyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills), que simulam aquelas funcionalidades. No demais bom trabalho, fico grato por ter despendido seu valioso tempo em me ajudar. Daqui em diante deixa comigo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Recomendo primeiramente criar um `iframe` usando o atributo `sandbox`, isto pra "tentar" trazer alguma segurança, de preferencia o que puder fazer em HTML faça, ficar criando coisas dinâmicas com JS funciona bem, mas toma tempo e torna a manutenção mais complexa, então o que puder ser HTML faça em HTML.

Os valores do atributo sandbox:

- **allow-same-origin:** Permite que o conteúdo a ser tratada como sendo de sua origem normal. Se esta chave não é utilizado, o conteúdo incorporado é tratada como sendo a partir de uma única origem.
- **allow-top-navigation:** Permite que o contexto de navegação incorporado para navegar pelo conteúdo (carga) para o contexto de navegação de nível superior. Se esta chave não é utilizado, esta operação não é permitido.
- **allow-forms:** Permite que o contexto de navegação incorporado para enviar formulários. Se esta chave não é utilizado, esta operação não é permitido.
- **allow-popups:** Permite que popups (como de window.open).
- **allow-scripts:** Permite que o contexto de navegação incorporado para executar scripts (mas não criar janelas pop-up). Se esta chave não é utilizado, esta operação não é permitido.
- **allow-pointer-lock:** Permite que o contexto de navegação incorporado para usar a API Pointer Lock.

Pode-se usar o atributo do IFRAME que deve alterar é o `srcdoc`, mas pra depurar o código você pode usar `URL.createObjectURL`, assim é possível detectar a linha que deu problema (dica do @TobyMosque).

Faça estrutura html ficaria assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sandbox</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <style type="text/css">
    .fiddle textarea, .fiddle iframe {
        width: 420px;
        height: 240px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form class="fiddle">
        html:<br>
        <textarea id="fiddle-html">
        &lt;div class="foo"&gt;Foo bar&lt;/div&gt;
        &lt;p&gt;Baz&lt;/p&gt;
        </textarea>
        <hr>

        css:<br>
        <textarea id="fiddle-css">
        .foo {
            background-color: #f00;
            color: #fff;
        }

        p {
            color:red
        }
        </textarea>

        <hr>

        javascript:<br>
        <textarea id="fiddle-js">
        setTimeout(function() {
            alert("Olá mundo");
            console.log(1, 2, 3);
        }, 2000);
        </textarea>
        <hr>

        <iframe id="fiddle-sandbox" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms allow-modals"></iframe>

        <hr>

        <button type="button" id="run">Testar</button>
    </form>

    <!--// O script precisa ficar no final pois assim é mais rápido que onload -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="fiddle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

O `fiddle.js` deve obter os conteúdos dos campos assim (requer suporte no HTML5):

```
(function () {
    var
        currentUrl,
        currentContent,
        iframeContent;

    var
        running = false,
        supportBlob;

    var
        runButton = document.getElementById("run"),
        jsField   = document.getElementById("fiddle-js"),
        cssField  = document.getElementById("fiddle-css"),
        htmlField = document.getElementById("fiddle-html"),
        result    = document.getElementById("fiddle-result"),
        target    = document.getElementById("fiddle-sandbox");

    var mainCharset = "characterSet" in document ?
                        document.characterSet : (
                            document.inputEncoding ||
                            document.charset ||
                            document.defaultCharset
                        ) || "UTF-8";

    var tpl = '<!DOCTYPE html>\n' +
                '<html>\n' +
                '<head>\n' +
                '<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">\n' +
                '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="' +
                'text/html; charset=' + mainCharset + '">\n' +
                '<title>Running<\/title>\n' +
                '<style type="text/css">\n{%css%}\n<\/style>\n' +
                '<\/head>\n' +
                '<body>\n' +
                '{%html%}\n' +
                '<script type="text\/javascript">\n{%js%}\n<\/script>\n' +
                '<\/body>\n' +
                '<\/html>';

    //Adiciona evento ao botão testar
    runButton.onclick = runEvt;

    checkIframe();

    function checkIframe(callback)
    {
        setTimeout(function() {
            iframeContent = target.contentWindow ||
                            target.contentDocument.document ||
                            target.contentDocument;

            if (callback) {
                callback();
            }
        }, 10);
    }

    function writeInFrame()
    {
        result.removeChild(target);
        target.src = "about:blank";
        result.appendChild(target);

        checkIframe(function() {
            iframeContent.document.open();
            iframeContent.document.write(currentContent);
            iframeContent.document.close();

            running = false;
        });
    }

    function runEvt()
    {
        if (running) {
            return;
        }

        running = true;

        currentContent = tpl.replace(/\{%css%\}/,  cssField.value)
                            .replace(/\{%js%\}/,   jsField.value)
                            .replace(/\{%html%\}/, htmlField.value);

        if (supportBlob === false || !URL.createObjectURL) {
           writeInFrame();
           return;
        }

        //Remove URL antiga, se existir
        if (currentUrl) {
            URL.revokeObjectURL(currentUrl);
        }

        var blobData = new Blob([currentContent], { "type": "text/html" });

        //Cria url com os dados do Blob
        currentUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blobData);

        //Troca src do iframe
        target.src = currentUrl;

        //IE11 não carrega urls do tipo `blob:`, isso é um pequeno teste
        if (typeof supportBlob !== "boolean") {
            setTimeout(function() {
                try {
                    supportBlob = iframeContent.location.href === currentUrl;
                } catch (ee) {
                    //Se o navegador não suportar o sandbox ocorre erro de segurança
                    supportBlob = false;
                }

                if (!supportBlob) {
                    writeInFrame();
                }

                running = false;
            }, 50);
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: acho que no caso do AP talvez seja interessante usar `URL.createObjectURL` para criar documentos distintos para o `CSS`, `JS` e `HTML`,  e setar o `src` para do` iframe` para o link `HTML`, desta forma fica mais facil até para ele adicionar uma função para abrir o snippet em outra janela e debugar o JavaScript.

Comment: @TobyMosque otima ideia :)

Comment: @TobyMosque Legal, sua intenção aqui é toda voltada para "iframe" bem semelhante a essa [Como eu coloco um botão dentro de iframe](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/78129/como-eu-coloco-um-bot%C3%A3o-dentro-de-iframe) Cito ela como fonte referência em partes, onde você deu como resposta a criação do documento HTML na memória.