# Como observar um erro no elemento iframe com atributo "sandbox"

Tags: javascript, html5, iframe

Tenho em meu documento um `iframe` com o atributo `sandbox`.

Com `javasript` eu faço a leitura de um arquivo `Markdown` e faço o parse usando a biblioteca [showdonwjs](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown) e adiciono esse resultado ao atributo `srcdoc` do `iframe` e o resultado é o esperado.

Contudo os arquivos vem de origem dos usuários e estarão visíveis a outros usuários por isso faço uso do atributo `sandbox`.

Quando no arquivo `Markdown` houver um **script**... a página aonde esta o `iframe` lança um erro no `console` do navegador (óbvio se o atributo impede a execução, quando há uma tentativa deve haver um erro).

Como posso (se é que posso) observar este erro em `javascript`? Saber se houve um erro?

Desde já grato.

---

**update**

#### page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
   <title>Teste</title>
</head>
<body id="body">
   <iframe id="frame" sandbox></iframe>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/showdownjs/showdown/develop/dist/showdown.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       var md = '###Hello Word <script>alert("!")<\/script>';
       var converter = new showdown.Converter();
       var MDtoHTML = converter.makeHtml(md)
       var ifrm = $('#frame')
       ifrm.attr('srcdoc', MDtoHTML);
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**jsFiddle**
[Exeplo](https://jsfiddle.net/hgmzov4g/)

Bom esse é o print do referido erro! Ele acontece então creio que minha dúvida tem minimamente sentido! Poderia (se for possível "observar") exibir um pop-up,  banner ou mesmo registrar um log, identificar uploaders mal intencionados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Podes fazer um jsFiddle com um exemplo do que estás a fazer?

Comment: Até tentei usa o Fiddle más não consegui. Vou atualizar a pergunta e coloar parte do code.

Comment: Adicionado exemplo no  jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hgmzov4g/

Comment: **Relacionado:** http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/142711/3635

Comment: Eu não vi o que poderia estar relacionado. Na pergunta de exemplo o usuário quer executar javascript no iframe sandboxed o que é exatamente o que não quero.

Comment: Não relacionado não é igual, se olhar no código eu explico como pegar o log, não é isso o que quer? E entenda que relacionado não quer dizer duplicada, o link só serve para ajudar futuros visitantes ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu não disse "duplicada"... más acho que você leu a pergunta não o conteúdo dela. Meu `iframe` não possui permissões no atributo `sandbox` ou seja, ele não executa scripts.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Verdade que não sei de onde o erro é lançado más acredito ser do documento que comporta o `iframe`. Eu segui (ontem) o seu link e testei com um `iframe` sem permissões e o erro foi o mesmo até "printei" seu exemplo https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8Eac.png

Comment: A mensagem fala que allow-script não foi setada, mas o exemplo que eu postei tem sim isso: `<iframe id="fiddle-sandbox" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms allow-modals"></iframe>`, vou testar aqui.

Comment: Como eu disse: você não leu minha pergunta. Meu iframe não possui permissões no atributo sandbox... para testar seu exemplo removi as permissões porque "a ideia é não executar javascript no iframe" quero somente "observar" esta exceção para poder tratar ou mostrar um alerta (no documento de origem)

Comment: @LauroMoraes Desculpe a pergunta, mas para que seria usada essa informação? Quero dizer, mesmo que você identifique que existe javascript no markdown do usuário isso não quer dizer imediatamente que ele é malicioso. Afinal, markdown suporta exemplos em javascript.

Comment: @LauroMoraes estive pesquisando sobre a sua pergunta hoje durante muito tempo, acredito que não é possível capturar essa exceção pois ela se dá dentro do iframe em modo sandbox, ou seja, nem mesmo a view que expõe ele tem acesso já que o allow-same-origin não está habilitado. Minha sugestão é: tente implementar ou buscar um sanitizer javascript para verificar o input do usuário, caso o input não passe em um desses sanitizer significa que ele tem um possível código "malicioso", é uma saída para o seu problema

Comment: Pois é eu procurei na MDN, no W3C e na HTML SPEC e em acho uma centena (sério centena) de sites e nada. Acho estranho se fosse ao que parece um tratamento interno do navegador nem mesmo pude encontrar referencia sobre Chrome ou Firefox...

Comment: @LauroMoraes como não usou o arroba `@GuilhermeNascimento` não recebi tua mensagem, faz algum tempo, vc disse que eu não li, mas não foi sobre isto que eu quis dizer, o problema é que estou tentando lhe explicar uma coisa e vc esta se apegando a outra. Eu apenas estava explicando o controle que é possivel ter sobre o IFRAME através do atributo `sandbox="..."`. Eu não disse que o teu iframe possui, eu disse justamente o contrário. Não posso afirmar que é possivel obter os erros do console diretamente do iframe, mas é possivel obter no escopo global. Tem um link sobre o assunto, vou postar aqui.

Answer (score 2):

Não existe uma forma para que possamos acessar os valores do console e "observar" o warnings / errors emitidos pelas libs internas do javascript(v8, chakra, etc). Desconheço essa funcionalidade em qualquer engine na atual versão.

O que você poderia fazer para contornar o problema apresentado é usar outro modelo.

Por exemplo:

```
 var md = '###Hello Word <script>alert("!")<\/script>';
 var match = md.match(/<script\b[^<]*(?:(?!<\/script>)<[^<]*)*<\/script>/gi);

 if(match && match.length) {
    console.log('Aqui existe script, devemos emitir um erro para o código malicioso');
    return;
 }

 var converter = new showdown.Converter();
 var MDtoHTML = converter.makeHtml(md)
 var ifrm = $('#frame')
 ifrm.attr('srcdoc', MDtoHTML);
```

Segue o exemplo 
https://jsfiddle.net/hgmzov4g/7/

Comment: desculpe más não considero esta "técnica" útil para filtrar (o que não é o caso pois o caso é impedir) o uso de javascript visto que existe infinitas possibilidades de executar javascript no documento sem necessariamente declarar uma tag `<script>` **exemplos** https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet#IFRAME

Comment: ha, quanto ao meu comentário de que "possa ser um tratamento interno" não me referi a observar este tratamento (possivelmente interno) más sim de não encontrar referencia na documentação da especificação nem dos browsers Chromium (que também é base do Chrome) e Firefox que tem o fonte aberta.

Answer (score -2):

Você precisa colar um **try** onde o código causa error, e usar um **catch** para tratar o error.

Você pode conferir mais informações de como usar declarações **try..catch** no site [Mozilla para desenvolvedores](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

Comment: Grato pela resposta más `try\catch` não captura este erro. Testado em **Chrome**, **FireFox** e **Opera**

Answer (score -2):

Se o try catch não funcionar, você pode tentar usar um regex na string antes de transformar o Markdown procurando pela tag script e retirar.

Comment: Grato pela resposta más `try\catch` não captura este erro. Testado em **Chrome**, **FireFox** e **Opera**